# Added reference, class is still not defined?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web site project where I need to use the System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml class. I added the Dll System.Security as a reference and imported the namespace into my project. 
It compiles successfully but when I debug the project I get a compilation error:

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml' is not defined.
```

What gives?

**Edit:** I run Windows XP Pro 64bit OS

Comment: I believe that in web site projects, references to GAC assemblies get stored in web.config, you can check if system.security assembly is present there otherwise runtime will not load the assembly.

Comment: It wasn't there, but I add the row, rebuilt the project and tried to run it again. The error still occurs. :/

Answer (score 0):

how you can compiles successfuly and get compilation error wile debug?
Try to reload your VS...

Comment: I have no idea, I'm really clueless. Will try!